# Finding hidden services

Tags: stem, address

There are several questions here, 1) maybe I should chop the Question to pieces? All four questions marked with numbers as before.

I am considering to host file server for a company in tor. The idea is to use ownCloud to store confidential information. The address will be given only to the few trusted employees. 2) What worries me is wether the address of my hidden service can be discovered through HS-directory?

Being a sceptic, I wanted to try it myself. I didn't find a ready tool, so I started to examine Stem package. I was able to get the fingerprint of the public key of a random server, but not the public key itself. The fingerprint did not give reasonable address when encoded to base32 and concatenated to 16 chars. Then I read that address is not just a hash of the public key.  3) Apparently information [at tor project site](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/HiddenServiceNames) is outdated?  4) Could I calculate .onion domain address from a fingerprint or other information I receive from descriptor?

Comment: Question 2 is now practically answered.  Although HS directory can not probably do that, a relay can catch onion-addresses. I am still curious wether the fingerprints can be used to deduce the addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your site onion address could be captured by relays on the TOR network, if you want to make it confidential, you should consider making the hidden service "invitation only" or "password protected"

Comment: OK, I will certainly protect the data with passwords and encryption. The reason for using tor is just to avoid unwanted attention.  The users and the server can not easily be correlated.